# It is possible to access a subdirectory of an SD Card without receiving the forbidden 403 message?

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server, file-permissions, sd-card

How procedure for a sub-directory mapped as a virtual-host using an SDCard formatted for a Mac OS Expanded (Journaling), have permission to correct that it does not receive a Forbidden 304 message.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@gutennews.local
   DocumentRoot "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/gutten-news/guten-news-web"
   ServerName local.gutennews.com.br  
   ServerAlias www.local.gutennews.local
   ErrorLog "logs/dummy-gutennews-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/dummy-gutennews-access.log" common
   php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
   setEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
   <Directory "/Volumes/SDCARD/sd_projects/gutten-news/guten-news-web">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Satisfy Any
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You may want to try using e.g. `Require all granted` in place of `Satisfy Any`, at least for testing. One other option to try also might be just to create a symlink to the project in a known directory Apache can access.

Comment: I even thought of creating a symblink inside the htdocs folder pointing to the SD card, but I didn't try it, it might suddenly work.